# Large file Copy speed issue

Tags: clipboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copy to USB memory stick really slow?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122113/copy-to-usb-memory-stick-really-slow)

I have looked at the various email regarding speed of copying large files and it has been coming on for a long time.

I have a USB 3 memory stick and a laptop that dual boots into Windows 7 64bit or Ubuntu Linux 64bit. When attempt to copy large files in Windows, it goes through quite quickly. When I copy the same files using Ubuntu, it always takes a lot longer than Windows.

I am using all the same hardware as well as the same files.

In Linux, the copy transfer rate starts at about 30Mb/s and reduces down to 10Mb/s.

I have notices similar type of reduction of speed when I copy large file from Linux to Linux over the network (samba share). When I copy the same files using a Windows client and a Linux server over samba it flies.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [Possible](http://askubuntu.com/q/122113/12864) [duplicates](http://askubuntu.com/q/156640/12864)?